Pulling values from AsyncStorage to update state in new component
I am new to JS / RN and facing this issue with my first app.
I set data in an onboarding screen and then on the next screen I have about 10 keys I want to check if there is a value in AsyncStorage and if so, update state. I tried to do this with a useEffect and AsyncStorage.getItem, using setData of a variable (created using const [data, setData] = useState({item:key}) - I think it's called a nested object). This caused an infinite loop / no variables being set depending on my implementation, so I have resorted to creating individual useState objects, plus functions to pull the data from AsyncStorage and then calling these inside a useEffect to run on render (i.e. with an emtpy array as the second variable). This feels very inefficient - what am I doing wrong and how can I improve this?
export default function Profile({ navigation }) {
  const { signOut } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const [userName, updateUserName] = React.useState(null);
  // 9 more of these
  async function getUserName() {
    try {
      const savedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userName');
      if (savedData != null) {updateUserName(savedData)}
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  // 9 more of these

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getUserName();
    // 9 more of these
  }, []);

Many thanks for any responses / advice / resources.

Looks like a design problem rather than the RN itself. What you're doing is perfectly fine. One thing I'd change is moving the getUserName so it'd be more semantically correct instead of skipping function dependencies in the useEffect hook (providing empty array). Or, eventually, transforming getUserName to useCallback. Apart from that, have you tried multiGet/multiMerge? Looks like something that could help you avoid these multiple useState definitions.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage#multiget
https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage#multimerge

I don't know how you tried to implement the object state before, but here is a working example :
const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    userName: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const getAsyncStorageData = async () => {
      const userName = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userName");
      const email = await AsyncStorage.getItem("email");
      const phone = await AsyncStorage.getItem("phone");

      setData({
        userName: userName ?? "",
        email: email ?? "",
        phone: phone ?? "",
      });
    };

    getAsyncStorageData()
      .then()
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, []);

The state is initialized with all the props set as empty string (if you can use typescript, it could be implemented using null or undefined instead of empty strings).
Inside the useEffect, we can't await async methods, so I created a function that will be awaited using .then with error managed in the .catch.
The getAsyncStorageData function fetch all data from async storage and set it to the object state with a single call.
The ?? syntax is a sugar for a ternary condition userName ? userName : ""
I hope this can help you!
If you need more information, you can refer to the React documentation on updating object in state

This is exactly what I needed - thank you for taking the time to give such a comprehensive reply, and the resource shared is also very useful, thanks!
